# Model isn't binding when I send JSON to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I might be overlooking something but my JSON payload isn't being binded at all for my controller. I have tried making a class where it has a `List<Models.UpdateChatRequestModel> Chats` but that hasn't worked for me either. I have tried using an array name but that hasn't seem to work either.

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateChatRequest(IList<Models.UpdateChatRequestModel> request)
{
    var model = new Models.ChatModel();

    return Json(model);
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class UpdateChatRequestModel
{
    public int UserID
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int LastID
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
class Chat {
    constructor(UserID, LastID) {
        this.UserID = UserID;
        this.LastID = LastID;
    }
}
var chats = [new Chat(0, 1), new Chat(1, 4)];

function RequestChatUpdate() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Chat/UpdateChatRequest',
        data: JSON.stringify(chats),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("got response from chat update");
        }
    });
}
```

JSON being sent from `RequestChatUpdate()`:

```
[{"UserID":0,"LastID":1},{"UserID":1,"LastID":4}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer.

You have to have `[FromBody]` in front of the model parameter like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateChatRequest([FromBody] IList<Models.UpdateChatRequestModel> request)
{
    var d = ModelState;
    var model = new Models.ChatModel();

    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: did you need to add somethings that I've suggested you?

Comment: no, apparently the new framework update required the [FromBody] attribute for some weird reason.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add the name for your JSON, Looks like this

```
var request = JSON.stringify({ 'request': chats });
```

Then your ajax request would become

```
function RequestChatUpdate() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Chat/UpdateChatRequest',
        data: request,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("got response from chat update");
        }
    });
}
```

**Updated**

According to [this](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) specs, it said that

> In order to bind the JSON correctly in ASP.NET Core, you must modify
>   your action to include the attribute [FromBody] on the parameter. This
>   tells the framework to use the content-type header of the request to
>   decide which of the configured IInputFormatters to use for model
>   binding

So that's the reason why you need to add `[FromBody]`

Comment: Did you try change the type of param in action - controller? from `IList<Models.UpdateChatRequestModel> request)` to `Models.UpdateChatRequestModel [] request`

Comment: pls try send `var request = JSON.stringify({ 'request':  [{"UserID":0,"LastID":1},{"UserID":1,"LastID":4}]})`

Comment: Still no results

Comment: Pls add `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205328/discussion-between-anonymous-and-mark-mueller).

Comment: Did you try it? @Mark Mueller add  `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: move on chat to give me all of things that you have changed so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Mark Mueller